# How can I combine categories?

Tags: stata

I have a variable `fruit` with the following categories:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
20
25
```

I want to collapse these as below:

```
1
2
3
4
5+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your example:

```
clear
input fruit
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
20
25
end

tabulate fruit

      fruit |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          1        8.33        8.33
          2 |          1        8.33       16.67
          3 |          1        8.33       25.00
          4 |          1        8.33       33.33
          5 |          1        8.33       41.67
          6 |          1        8.33       50.00
          7 |          1        8.33       58.33
          8 |          1        8.33       66.67
          9 |          1        8.33       75.00
         10 |          1        8.33       83.33
         20 |          1        8.33       91.67
         25 |          1        8.33      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         12      100.00
```

The following works for me:

```
replace fruit = 5 if fruit >= 5

tabulate fruit

      fruit |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          1        8.33        8.33
          2 |          1        8.33       16.67
          3 |          1        8.33       25.00
          4 |          1        8.33       33.33
          5 |          8       66.67      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         12      100.00
```